# Boundedness in dimension 1 and 2.

Tags: analysis

Consider $\psi$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|\psi(x)|}{|x|^{1-m/2}}\leq C,$$
where $C$ is a positive constant. Why in dimensions 1 and 2 is sufficies to assume that $\psi$ is bounded, to satisfies this? Why in greater dimensions not?

Comment: $m=2$ is obvious.

Comment: if $m=1$, it is $|\psi|\le C/|x|^{1/2}$ when $|x|$ is large

Comment: And if $m\gt2$, the inequality fails even if $\psi$ is constant.